# Laravel 5.4 Collection Map Return Values

Tags: php, laravel, optimus

I'm having trouble creating a function on collection map with return values.

```
public function getCollectionFakeId($collection, $fieldNames){

        $optimus = $this->optimus;

        $result = $collection->map(function($item, $key) use ($optimus, $fieldNames) {

                return [
                    $fieldNames[0] =>$optimus->encode($item->id),
                    $fieldNames[1] => $item->lastname
                ];


        }) ;

        dd($result);
        return  json_decode(json_encode($result), FALSE);


    }
```

As you can see the return fieldNames[0] is being hardcoded. I don't know how many fieldNames it will received. I need to return those fieldnames with obfuscated Id. So basically The only changed is the Id. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see the fieldNames are just 2 but what if it becomes 5 or 6. I don't really know how many fieldNames they are going to pass in the parameter. How can I return it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will encounter this problem. Here is my solution...

```
public function getCollectionFakeId($collection, $fieldNames){

        $optimus = $this->optimus;

        $result = $collection->map(function($item, $key) use ($optimus, $fieldNames) {

                $mapFieldNames = array_map(function($v) use ($optimus, $item) {
                    if( $v == 'id'){
                        return $optimus->encode($item->id);
                    }
                    else{
                        return $v;
                    }
                }, $fieldNames);

               return $mapFieldNames;
        }) ;

        dd($result);
        return  json_decode(json_encode($result), FALSE);


    }
```

The result is the same. AWESOME!